# How to track a user's session without requiring them to login with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have an application that has an actual map of objects that any visitor can view as long as they have the correct access code.  I don't require the user to login because I don't want to make them create an account as it is unnecessary.  I want to allow the users to mark the objects on the map with a check and save the edits within the session.  So if the user refreshed the page or they close the application and reopen it an hour or so later, I would like to save their marks based off their session id.  But I am confused on how to set this up without requiring them to login because I am unsure how the sessions would work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Sessions in Rails work the exact same way regardless if you have a proper authentication system or not.

When a first time visitor visits your application the sessions middleware creates a session identifier. This is a cryptographic hash that is kept by the server and also passed to the user in a cookie.

This lets you identify users across requests.

This session identifier is also linked to a session storage. By default this is `ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` which lets you store session data in a encrypted cookie held by the client.  This is where you would normally store a user id. Since its a cookie the amount of storage space is very limited. If you want to store more data in the session you can use a different store such as Memcached, Redis or ActiveRecord.

But what you may want to consider is creating (guest) user records implicitly without the normal sign up procedure. I would just use [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden) and have a bare bones user model and a cron tab that cleans out unneeded data periodically.

This gives you a database oriented application model where you can use associations and build it like a standard rails application instead of the untestable mess that results when someone goes bonkers with sessions.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement Cookies (with their permission of course).  You can store basic data in it, or even create a sort of ID for them so when they return you can restore their settings